# test class for Custom settings in Account

Tags: trigger

```
for (AccXYZ__c mdm : mdmObjs){
                    system.debug(' *** mdm '+mdm);
                    String fieldName = mdm.Field_Name__c;
                    system.debug('***** fieldName:'+fieldName);
                    vStrFldValNew = string.valueOf(vSObjNew.get(fieldName));
                    vStrFldValOld = String.valueOf(vSobjOld.get(fieldName));    
                    system.debug('#########vStrFldValNew'+vStrFldValNew+'#######vStrFldValOld'+vStrFldValOld);       
                    if (vStrFldValNew != vStrFldValOld){
                        mdmFieldUpdated = true;
                              system.debug('########MDM Field Updated to be true SECOND########');
                    }
        }
```

For this portion of trigger i am writing a test class.Creating object for custom setting on account and passing random values to the 'Name' and 'Field_Name__c' of Account XYZ cutom Object.Like this -

```
Account accObj = new Account(Name ='Random',RecordTypeId='012b00000005EF3',CommercialName__c='Com');
AccXYZ__c accXYZObj = new AccXYZ__c();

    accMDMObj.Name = 'ChangeGood';
    accMDMObj.Field_Name__c = 'Phone';
    insert accMDMObj;

    accMDMObj.Name = 'Good';
    accMDMObj.Field_Name__c = 'Fax';
    update accMDMObj;

    update accObj;
```

But still i am this in logs :

```
DEBUG|***** fieldName:Fax
DEBUG|#########vStrFldValNew: null#######vStrFldValOld: null
```

How to pass some not null value ....Just want these two to be different !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that accMDMObj is a reference to the custom setting where an Account field name is nominated (to 'Fax'), the test class is missing assigning any value to the Account.Fax field. So add these lines to the end of the test code you show:

```
accObj.Fax = '12345678';
updated accObj;
accObj.Fax = '87654321';
updated accObj;
```

and you should see these values coming through as the old/new values.

Comment: `accObj.RecordType.Name = 'XYZstr';`
This throws system null pointer exception....how to give value for Recordtype Name in account !!!

In the same class

Comment: @codeGoose You have to assign the ID `accObject.RecordTypeId = [select Id from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'XYZstr'].Id;`.

Comment: `accObj.RecordTypeId = [select Id,Name from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Account' and Name = 'Company'].Id;`
`Update accObj;`

`|DEBUG|#####accObj.RecordType.Name:null#####oldAccount.RecordType.Name:null`

Still facing same thing !!!

Comment: @codeGoose Note sure why you want to check that value. But if you do you will need to query to get it `String name = [select RecordType.Name from Account where Id = : accObj.Id].RecordType.Name;`.